# CURL syntax error

Tags: json, curl, cmd

I am trying to use CURL to put JSON data in my request by using this syntax:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"firstName":"First", "lastName":"last", "email":"user@xyz.com", "username":"user1", "password":"pass1"}' 127.0.0.1:3001/users
```

now the CMD is showing this error:
[image: as you can see]

Please help!

Comment: Windows doesn't treat `'` the same way a Unix shell would.

Comment: So what should be done to resolve it? @user2357112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I used:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"firstName\": \"First\", \"lastName\": \"last\", \"email\": \"user@xyz.com\", \"username\": \"user1\", \"password\": \"pass1\"}" 127.0.0.1:3001/users
```

And it worked!
**Shout out to Ross Kinard** for helping with a temporary solution so that this question now specifies both way in which we can post using CURL in cmd.

Answer (score 1):

I'd let batch do the escaping by replacing all `"` with `\"`

```
set "json={"firstName":"First", "lastName":"last", "email":"user@xyz.com", "username":"user1", "password":"pass1"}"
set "json=%json:"=\"%"
echo curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "%json%" 127.0.0.1:3001/users
```

Remove the echo in front of curl before using.

---

- If running a batch in powershell curl without extension will use the alias to Invoke-Webrequest instead of curl.exe
- I Windows 10 Version 1803 is  curl.exe included (C:\Windows\system32\curl.exe V7.55.1.0)
- If you need a special version of curl the location `C:\Windows\system32\` is presumably before in the environment path, so include the path to **your** curl then.

Comment: Well this is a nice brilliant solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem earlier, and my solution was to save the post data in a .json file and call it in the request.

```
curl -v -X POST https://someSite.com/randrand \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'User-Agent: (iPhone; iOS 7.1; Scale/2.00)' \
  --data @data.json
```

Comment: where the file must be saved? like in which directory? Should that be same as where cmd is currently?

Comment: I saved it in the same directory I was running the terminal in, in my case, my desktop.

Comment: Thanks! It solved the problem for now but what if I don't wanna use this? @Ross Kinard

Comment: I tried for a long time to find the right syntax for the data section, but I was not able to with the elements I was posting using the terminal on a Mac.  If you find a better answer, let me know.

Comment: Yeah I'll let you know certainly if I find something out.